# How to convert hex string to hex number?

Tags: python

I have integer number in ex. 16 and i am trying to convert this number to a hex number. I tried to achieve this by using hex function but whenever you provide a integer number to the hex function it returns string representation of hex number,

```
my_number = 16
hex_no = hex(my_number)    
print type(hex_no) // It will print type of hex_no as str.
```

Can someone please tell me how to convert hex number in string format to simply a hex number.
Thanks!!

Comment: How does this matter? You need the hex representation only for printing. A number is a number; decimal, binary and hex are just representations to the outside world.

Comment: Why does the title say "string to number" when "number to hex string" is really what you want?

Comment: Strange. `print hex_no` should NOT print quotes. Can you check that again?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - I want to use the converted hex number for further calculations.  @poke - I have edited my code and added a statement proving that hex is returning str() type of data. @Manoj Govindan - Nice Catch! Thanks..

Comment: @Rupesh: If you want to do calculations with it, why convert it to hex at all? `0x0F*0x0F` is the same as `15*15`. If you print an integer, it too will be transformed into a string. So what?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: I know this work around but i just wanted to know why we can't perform operations directly on hex number or in fact why can't we represent a hex number as integer does?  why does it represents hex as string always?

Comment: It doesn't always represent hex as string, it's a meaningless question. There's no such thing as   a a hex integer or a decimal integer - it's all binary inside the computer in any case. When you convert an integer into its hexadecimal string representation (which was what hex does) then of course you get a string...

Comment: @Rupesh: Isn't this a case of thinking in another language? Perhaps Java?

Comment: Integers are integers. They are not hexadecimal, decimal, binary, or anything else. The base only comes into it when you're talking about the string representation of an integer (including when you print it out).

Comment: @Paul: >>It doesn't always represent hex as string, it's a meaningless question. : Can u please elaborate it bit more.  >>There's no such thing as a a hex integer or a decimal integer - it's all binary inside the computer in any case. : It's an universal truth but if you create a variable = int(12), it will return you decimal integer 12 and not string but if u try to do it the same with the hex() you will get a string representation of it.  >>@Paul's last statement : This is what i want to know why the behavior is in this way.

Comment: i guess is quite clear enough and straight forward, why downvote? Any explaination?

Comment: int() converts a string (or float) to an integer (not a "decimal integer", just an integer). hex() converts an integer to a string. So they are different functions returning different types, both doing what they are documented to do.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for correcting me in the explanation of int(). as per documentation, hex() returns the string formatted hexadecimal representation of integer or long integer[Ref. Python 2.6.2 api doc]. It would be great if you can just tell me whether is it possible to perform arithmetic operation on hexadecimal numbers? because i know a work around in which we convert the numbers to the integer, perform action on them and again convert the result again back to hex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there's no such thing as a "hexadecimal number". There are integers (which don't have any radix) and the string representations of integers (which can be hex, decimal, binary or something else). You can't do arithmetic directly on strings. So it's not a "workaround" to convert them to the integer, it's the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @Paul: 1) Integers have decimal(10) as there by default radix in python [Ref. int() api doc]. 2) Hex, Decimal, binary are representations methods used to represent integers, but those are not string representations. Ref: C:\>python
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0x12 + 0x13
37
 - according to the above code 0x12 is not string, it's an integer.  Anyways still thanks for clearing my doubts.. :)

Comment: The string representation that int uses has a default radix of 10. Not the integer. It is still meaningless to say an integer (that on the computer is represented  as binary) is a decimal integer. But if thinkking that way works for you, so be it.

Comment: Hey thanks Paul for the good lesson. I could find out and realized that hex, binary and octal are nothing but string representation of integer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
>>> print int('0x10', 16)
16
```

Answer (score 4):

**Sample Code :**

```
print "%x"%int("2a",16)
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking how to convert the string format hexadecimal value '16' into an integer  (that is, end up with an integer with decimal value 22)? It's not clear from your question. If so, you probably want int('16', 16)

Comment: +1. Question is not clear. But this is a good answer if the OP is trying to read an integer from the hex string.

Comment: I want to get a hexadecimal value out of string formatted hexadecimal. ex. '0x16' i want it as 0x16

Comment: `0x16` *doesn't exist* in a running program! It is either `'0x16'` or `22` (= `int('0x16', 16)`).

Answer (score 2):

Using the string formatters (new first, then old):

```
>>> '{:x}'.format( 12345678 )
'bc614e'

>>> '%x' % ( 12345678 )
'bc614e'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, no apostrophes added.

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75708, Oct 26 2009, 08:23:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> my_number = 16
>>> hex_no = hex(my_number)
>>> print hex_no
0x10
>>> _
```

Note, by the way, that there's no such thing as a "hex number". Hex is just a way to *specify* a number value. In the computer's memory that number value is usually represented in binary, no matter how it's specified in your source code (decimal, hex, whatever).

Cheers & hth.,

– Alf

Comment: +1. `print` doesn't add quotes. Perhaps the OP is typing `hex_no` and hitting `enter`?

Answer (score 1):

I think here most of the answers were misinterpreted or they understood the question wrongly.

To answer to your question it is IMPOSSIBLE to convert resultant string representation of Hex data to Hex numbers(integer representation).

Because, when you convert an integer to hex by doing following

```
>>> a = hex(34)
>>> print type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> print a
0x22
>>> a
'0x22'
```

And some answers were confused here,

```
>>> print a
0x22
>>> a
'0x22'
```

When you type **print a** in interpreter it will result the string data **WITHOUT** quotes and If you simply type the variable name without using print statement then it would print the string data **WITH** single/double quotes.

Though the resultant value is **Hex data** but the representation is in **STRING**.

As per Python docs you cannot convert to Hex number as I told earlier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Python 2.6.5 on MS Windows Vista, the command line interpreter behaves this way:

```
>>>hex(16)
'0x10'
>>>print hex(16)
0x10
```

I guess this is the normal behavior:

```
>>>'abc'
'abc'
>>>print 'abc'
abc
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

```
def add_hex2(hex1, hex2):
    """add two hexadecimal string values and return as such"""
    return hex(int(hex1, 16) + int(hex2, 16))
print add_hex2('0xff', '0xff')  # 0x1fe
```